# Relative import error with flask

Tags: python, flask

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11536764/how-to-fix-attempted-relative-import-in-non-package-even-with-init-py), I am trying to run my [`flask web application`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/) from my `com_profiler` directory as `python -m api.index`, `python -m api.index.py`, `python api/index.py`. But none of these are working. The errors I am getting are in the order -

-> `ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package`

-> `attempted relative import beyond top-level package`

-> `SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import`

**Directory Structure**:

```
comp_profiler/
├── api
│   ├── bootstrap.sh
│   ├── index.py
│   └── __init__.py
├── __init__.py
├── pipelines.py
├── random_useragent.py
├── requirements.txt
├── scrapy.cfg
├── spiders
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── content_handler.py
│   ├── core_spider.py
│   ├── middlewares.py
│   ├── scrapper
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── corporatedir.py
│   │   ├── craft.py
│   │   ├── tofler.py
│   │   └── zaubacorp.py
│   ├── scrapper.py
│   ├── seed_list_generator.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   └── utility.py
```

index.py

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from ..spiders.seed_list_generator import SeedListGenerator

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/start-spider")
def hello_world():
    spider = SeedListGenerator()
    company_name = request.get_json()
    print(company_name)
    return "Hello world"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

I also tried running it from `api` directory, but no success.

Kindly let me know if I am missing something with flask setup, as I am just starting up with flask.

**Update:** I want to integrate `SeedListGenerator` as API call. Kindly suggest.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Either you can restructure your directory layout such that you don't need `..` import or you can turn the whole code base into a package. In any case you should have a separate script that invokes the app, i.e. the `..spiders` should be a `<package name>.spiders`.

Comment: By `package` in python, every directory should have empty `__init__.py`. Right? Please correct me if I got it wrong.

Comment: Yes but I mean you could also install the package (locally) via `pip` for example. But in any case, I would have that `index.py` script at the very top level, that is instead of inside the `api` directory it should go to `comp_profiler`. The main script invoking the other parts should sit atop.

Comment: What about `python -m comp_profiler.api.index`? If `api` is your top-level package you can't make relative imports beyond that.